# how to exit the entire app in a multiprocessing program

Tags: python, multiprocessing, exit

Here is the sample codes, just as the codes described, i want to exit the entire app in one running processing. but when i invoke the **exit(0)** function, some other processings are still running. so how to kill all the running processings at the same time? any help appreciated!

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def submit_process():
    sig = False

    #Here is some codes trying to change the value of the variable sig

    print "submit_process"

    if(sig == True):
        #Here i want to exit the entire program instead of the single thread only.
        #exit(0)
        pass

process_list = []
print "OK"
for i in range(10):
    process = Process(target = submit_process)
    process.start()
    process_list.append(process)

for i in range( len(process_list) ):
    process_list[i].join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `.terminate()` on everything in the process list. This is generally a bad idea though as subprocesses of your processes will become orphaned.

From [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html)

> terminate() Terminate the process. On Unix this is done using the
>   SIGTERM signal; on Windows TerminateProcess() is used. Note that exit
>   handlers and finally clauses, etc., will not be executed.
>
> Note that descendant processes of the process will not be terminated –
>   they will simply become orphaned.

In your case it would look something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def submit_process():
    sig = False

    #Here is some codes trying to change the value of the variable sig

    print "submit_process"

    if(sig == True):
        # Terminate all spawned processes
        for process in process_list:
          process.terminate()
        exit(0)

process_list = []
print "OK"
for i in range(10):
    process = Process(target = submit_process)
    process.start()
    process_list.append(process)

for i in range( len(process_list) ):
    process_list[i].join()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your process function (e.g. `submit_process`) has a loop where you can test for a condition, you could use an mp.Event for this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import logging

logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def submit_process(i, sig):
    logger.info("submit_process")
    while True:
        #Here is some codes trying to change the value of the variable sig
        if i == 0:
            time.sleep(2)
            sig.set()
            logger.info('SETTING sig')
        time.sleep(1)
        if sig.is_set():
            #Here i want to exit the entire program instead of the single thread only.
            #exit(0)
            logger.info('sig is set!')
            break
        else:
            logger.info('sig is NOT set!')            

process_list = []
logger.info("OK")
sig = mp.Event()
for i in range(3):
    process = mp.Process(target = submit_process, args = (i, sig, ))
    process.start()
    process_list.append(process)

for i in range( len(process_list) ):
    process_list[i].join()
```

yields

```
[INFO/MainProcess] OK
[INFO/Process-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-2] submit_process
[INFO/Process-3] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-3] submit_process
[INFO/Process-1] submit_process
[INFO/Process-2] sig is NOT set!
[INFO/Process-3] sig is NOT set!
[INFO/Process-2] sig is NOT set!
```

Here process-1 sets the mp.Event:

```
[INFO/Process-1] SETTING sig
```

Here the processes recognize that sig has been set and break out of the while loop:

```
[INFO/Process-3] sig is set!
[INFO/Process-3] process shutting down
[INFO/Process-3] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/Process-2] sig is set!
[INFO/Process-2] process shutting down
[INFO/Process-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/Process-1] sig is set!
[INFO/Process-1] process shutting down
[INFO/Process-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```